# LocalService to perform SMS forward?

Tags: android

I hope an app can forward SMS automatically when an SMS arrives. I think the service need to keep run in foreground to monitor SMS.

And I have to start and stop the service,and the service starts automatically  when moblie phone power on. How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: What you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"` to your manifest and  Create a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#broadcastreceivers) like following:

```
public class autostart extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(arg0,yourService.class);
        arg0.startService(intent);
        Log.i("Autostart", "started");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the sms using this piece of code.Create a Broadcast reciever as Yup said and send sms using service.

```
 <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:exported="true" > 
  <intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
  </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks! but why do I need send sms using service?

Comment: forward SMS automatically when an SMS arrives-----to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks! How to stop the monitor?

Comment: [Link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/android-broadcast-receiver-enable-and.html)